Why does operand 1 in a modr/m byte change depending on the decoding mode
I'm trying to figure out why the instruction changes from add [eax], al to add [rax], al when changing the decoding mode from x86 to x64.
The instruction bytes are 00 00
I think it might be because its being used to specify a memory location but I couldn't find anything to prove it

64 bit mode is strictly speaking a different ISA so machine code can mean something else. For example the REX prefixes are repurposed INC/DEC opcodes. It's just convenience that most opcodes mean the same thing. For each one, the instruction set reference gives the meaning depending on the mode. But yes, in 64 bit mode the default address size is 64 bits. You can force 32 bit with an address size override prefix so 67 00 00 would be add [eax], al.

As far as documentation, consult the Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Volume 1: Basic Architecture section 3.6.1 Operand Size and Address Size in 64-Bit Mode

This is because the default address size is 64 bits in 64-bit mode and 32 bits in 32-bit modes.
You can apply a 67 address-size override prefix to select an address size of 32 bits in 64-bit mods, however 64-bit address size is not available outside of 64-bit mode.

A 67 prefix in 32-bit mode gives you 16-bit addressing -- making 67 00 00 into add [bx+si], al.  I think you meant to say it gives you an address size of 32 bits in 64-bit mode.

@ChrisDodd Sorry, brain fart.  It's fixed now.
